# can i deeplink my product pages which are not allowed to be crawled by robots

Tags: google-search, noindex, meta-robots, deeplinks

I have a set of pages which i have blocked by the robots and i don't want them to appear in search results.

But if i am targetting users on this page via email/ad campaigns i want a possibility of them deep linking in android to my application in case that is installed.

So if i **add the google recommended alternate link on these pages**, would that **take it to application** ? (how does crawler get this meta if i have no-index on this page or i have blocked this from robots)

Example :

Page: http://www.example.com/page1 - non indexable
I add meta :

Now would this work ?

Comment: you wan users not to be allowed to search until they install your app, or I got it wrong?

Comment: No there are few urls that are not crawlable by crawler, i.e. i don't want them to be visible on google search, but if shared via email , it can open app if app is installed

Comment: so it's easy just no-index is enough

Comment: and anything else is just different kind of matter